# Why isn't this redux action promise resolving?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a redux action that returns a promise, so that the ui can respond accordingly based upon the result. This action sends a request to the backend, and when it gets a successful response from the server, it resolves.

redux action:

```
export const preauthorizePayment = (amount, connectedAccountId, customerId) => {
    console.log("action reached")
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: types.UPDATING })
        return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
            console.log("promise reached")
            axios.get(PRE_AUTH_ENDPOINT, {
                params: {
                    amount: amount,
                    customerId: customerId,
                    connectedAccountId: connectedAccountId
                }
            })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log("then reached...")
                    if (res.data.result == 'success') {
                        dispatch({ type: types.UPDATE_SUCCESS });
                        console.log("if reached...");
                        return resolve();
                    } else {
                        console.log("else reached...")
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
                        dispatch({
                            type: types.UPDATE_FAIL,
                            info: res.data.errorInfo,
                            errorCode: res.data.errorCode
                        })
                        return reject()
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    dispatch({ type: types.UPDATE_FAIL, errorInfo: err })
                    return reject()
                })
        })
    }
}
```

the UI piece looks like:

```
props.preauthorizePayment(amount, connectedAccountId, customerId)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("pre-auth then reached")
    // pre-auth success
    setCheckInModal(false)
    props.checkIn(props.evnt.id, props.role)
  })
  .catch(err => setCheckInModal(true))
```

What im experiencing is that everything is working properly up until the `resolve()` portion of the redux action. din the if block of the redux action's `then()`, the dispatch gets fired, the log fires, but it doesn't resolve. The UI piece's `then()` does not execute, no log, nothing. initially I didnt have the return keyword in the resolve line, and once I added it, it worked once. but then it stopped.

Whats going on?

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: There's no need to wrap the `axios.get...` code in `new Promise`, since `axios.get` already returns a Promise - this is a classic Promise anti-pattern - however, the code should still work.

Comment: the actual issue is you resolve when you should reject and you reject when you should resolve ... since the first callback in a Promise executor is resolve and teh second is reject ... you've named resolve reject, and reject resolve - the name of the function doesn't change what it does - if you hadn't used the anti-pattern, you would've been fine